# In R, rename_all matching exactly on period

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

```
> zed = data.frame(teamAbb = c('A', 'B'), team.abb = c('C', 'D'))
> zed %>% dplyr::rename_all(. %>% gsub('team.', '', .))
  bb abb
1  A   C
2  B   D
```

It seems like `team.` in the gsub is shorthand for "anything that starts with `team`", however we are looking to gsub exactly on "columns whose first 5 letters are `team.`". Output we are looking to achieve would then be:

```
> data.frame(teamAbb = c('A', 'B'), abb = c('C', 'D'))
  teamAbb abb
1       A   C
2       B   D
```

Comment: `gsub` uses regular expressions and `.` is a special character in regular expressions. If you want a literal period, you'll need to escape the period with slashes: `zed %>% dplyr::rename_all(. %>% gsub('team\\.', '', .))` or use `zed %>% dplyr::rename_all(. %>% gsub('team.', '', ., fixed=TRUE))`

Comment: Note that `rename_all()` has been superseded by `rename_with()` in the latest versions of `dplyr`.